AspNetCore DataProtection breaks OIDC login in Blazor app
I've got an installation of Duende Identity Server that's working fine with WebAPI and React apps.
I'm tring to make a Blazor app.
The server side gets set up like this
            builder.Services.AddAuthentication(options =>
                {
                    options.DefaultScheme = "Cookies";
                    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = "oidc";
                })
                    .AddCookie()
                    .AddOpenIdConnect("oidc", options =>
                    {
                        options.Authority = "https://account.wherever.co.uk";
                        options.ClientId = "blazor_experiments";
                        options.ClientSecret = "secret";
                        options.ResponseType = "code";
                        options.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = false;
                        options.Scope.Add("openid");
                        options.Scope.Add("profile"); // IdentityResourceClaims means this gets role.
                        options.Scope.Add("offline_access"); // Causes refresh token to be provided.
                        options.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true;

                        options.Events = new Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectEvents
                        {
                            OnRedirectToIdentityProvider = context =>
                            {
                                // Logging correlation ID.
context.Request.Headers.Add(LoggerScopeMiddleware.LogCorrelationIdHeaderName, context.HttpContext.TraceIdentifier);

                                // Done.
                                return Task.FromResult(0);
                            }
                        };

                        options.CallbackPath = "/signin-oidc";
                        options.SignedOutCallbackPath = "/signout-callback-oidc";

                    });

When I run the app the home page loads and I have a link to a page that requires authorisation which triggers the OIDC flow as expected:

The browser goes to the authorize endpoint on IdentityServer and shows the login form and I log in
The browser is sent back to /signin-oidc in my project which sets cookies .AspNetCore.CookiesC1, .AspNetCore.CookiesC2, and .AspNetCore.CookiesC3.

A new GET request is then sent to the authorized page (with the three cookies, as far as I can tell) but it triggers the OIDC flow again and this continues in a loop until IdentityServer eventually replies 429 (too many requests).
The project console contains lots of messages:
Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.KeyRingBasedDataProtector: Trace: Performing protect operation to key {bb49856c-dd11-4a42-89c0-ff06d8421485} with purposes ('MyApplication', 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectHandler', 'oidc', 'v1').
Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.KeyRingBasedDataProtector: Trace: Performing protect operation to key {bb49856c-dd11-4a42-89c0-ff06d8421485} with purposes ('MyApplication', 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectHandler', 'System.String', 'oidc', 'v1').

I've got
builder.Services.AddDataProtection()...

in my startup configured identically to IdentityServer and my webAPI project where it's working.
I've also tried without it, and with
            builder.Services.AddDataProtection()
                .PersistKeysToFileSystem(new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\Work\AspNetCoreDataProtection"))
                .SetApplicationName("BlazorThing");

but it makes no difference.
What is going on?

I had
            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseAuthorization();

the wrong way round. UseAuthentication must come before UseAuthorization.
And it also needs:
                    .AddCookie(options =>
                    {
                        options.Cookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.Lax; // Strict doesn't work. Don't know why.


Just come across your question and I've experienced this before when user was authenticated but not authorized to view the resource. Authorization is dependent upon Authentication so yes, these need to be the right way round! Good spot
